# dplyr: different variables defined based on different lists

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Take a dataset like

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:3,
                 animal = c("elephant", "bee", "dog))

listofmamals <- c("elephant", "dog", "cat")
listofinsects <- c("bee", "wasp")
```

To define the variables *mamal* and *insect* I could do

```
df <- df%>%
   mutate(mamal = (animal %in% listofmamals),
          insect = (animal %in% listofinsects))
```

But I would rather have a more automated approach based on the list:

```
listoflists <- list(listofmamals, listofinsects)
```

where, if I extend the listoflists, an extra variable is automatically created based on the additional element. I can think of a for-loop to do this, but ideally, there would be a dplyr-approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1

I think, rather than making lists and lists of lists, you'd be better off making a new table and using `bind_rows` each time you need to extend your categorisation table, then using `left_join` to get those categorisations onto your `df`.

So, for e.g., lets say you've got a categorisation table:

```
animals_df <- tibble(animal = c("elephant", "dog", "cat"), type = "mammal")
```

and you want to add to it:

```
new_animals_df <- tibble(animal = c("bee", "wasp"), type = "insect")
```

(tibble recycles the "insect" value for the column "type" as it's length 1).

Extend your original categorisation table:

```
animals_df <- bind_rows(animals_df, new_animals_df)
```

And now, to define which is which (I know it's totally redundant in this example, but running with it...):

```
left_join(df, animals_df)
```

### method 2

Ultimately, if you want to use lists and lists of lists, the way I'd do it might be a bit hacky, but I'd just convert the lists into something resembling the above table, and then `left_join` in the same way:

```
listofmammals <- c("elephant", "dog", "cat")
listofinsects <-  c("bee", "wasp")
listoflists <- list(listofmammals, listofinsects)
```

Make a table similar to the one we had before:

```
animal_types <- listoflists %>% map_df(~tibble(.), .id="type")
```

And then `left_join` it to get the categories:

```
left_join(animals, animal_types, by = c("animal" = "."))
```

Maybe there's a more elegant way of doing it with lists - in my list method I'm left with the "type" column being just 1's and 2's, which I'd then have to recode, which isn't very satisfactory. Personally, I find the first method far easier to understand and almost just as easy to type out.

Comment: I like the idea of using data.frame and joining to define new variables. I use it a lot. In this case, I didn't because the actual problem I need to solve is one or two steps more complicated. Apparently, my MWE was too minimal in this case. Either way, a good solution to the question I did ask

Comment: Ah! I suspected as much. Does method 2 not supply the necessary - obviously would need to mutate the type variable with a case_when or something, which may or may not be a pain depending on how many lists you've got, but I don't necessarily see why it couldn't be extended beyond that MWE.